# FBSDK OAuth error on Xcode, Swift - Graph API for app id "New App ID" called, but token has app id "old app ID"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-oauth, fbsdk

## Facebook OAuth error switching from one app ID to another

#### I worked with contract devs who created the iOS application on another Facebook app ID which i can't control. I am trying to switch it to mine but ran into an error that the token still is using the old App ID. I switched the AppID & the CFBundleURLSchemes in the Plist too. The app compiles with no errors & I am able to get through to FB OAuth but once I sign in, it doesn't go through.

This is the error that I'm receiving

```
2019-11-15 17:13:20.233275-0600 Imbue[28564:6158269] FBSDKLog: Failed to send AppEvents: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#100) Graph API for app id 472586343541363 called, but token has app id 2470569892995934, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 100;
        "fbtrace_id" = "AknZ_YjiTwxrvivhd6v2f_d";
        message = "(#100) Graph API for app id 472586343541363 called, but token has app id 2470569892995934";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
```

## (#100) Graph API for app id 472586343541363 called, but token has app id 2470569892995934,

#### This is the code I have for OAuth

```
 @objc private func authenticateWithFacebook() {
    LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { [weak self] (result, err) in
        guard let authResult = result else { self?.show(message: FailureMessage.Login.message); return }
        if err != nil || authResult.isCancelled {
            self?.show(message: FailureMessage.Login.message)
        }else {
            self?.presentProtectedPage()
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, have been wrestling with it all day & I feel like it's something super simple. Would appreciate your help as a newbie to swift.

Thanks!

Comment: Update - added a bridging header file & auth worked better but still showed same error.